# C# serialize XML ArrayList to List<SelectListItem>

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have an XML element that looks like this:

```
<myThings>
  <Thing>my first thing</Thing>
  <Thing>my second thing</Thing>
  <Thing>my third thing</Thing>
</myThings>
```

In a ViewModel I have:

```
[XmlArray("myThings")]
[XmlArrayItem("This")]
public List<String> MyThings { get;set;}
```

When deserializing from the XML, I end up with a List of strings (MyThings).

The problem is that I would like to have a list of "[SelectListItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem(v=vs.118).aspx)" instead of a simple list of strings.

For each selectListItem in the list, I would like to use the string of a "Thing" (provided in the XML) for both the `Text` and the `Value` property.

Any idea a convenient way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: please add the serializing code

Comment: why not just convert after deserializing?

Comment: I usually recommend using [XmlElement] instead of [XmlArray] to remove the extra layer of tags (myThings).  XML only allows a single root tag so you only need the array when it is the root.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no, you cannot specify how a type is serialized using the XmlSerializer if you do not own that type which is the case here. If you were to serialize a SelectListItem you end up with this structure in your array:

```
<myThings>
    <This>
      <Disabled>false</Disabled>
      <Selected>false</Selected>
      <Text>my first thing</Text>
      <Value>my first thing</Value>
    </This>
</myThings>
```

However you can specify your own type or use a conversion as others have also stated. This way your type defines how to serialize/deserialize but your business logic can make use directly of the `List<SelectListItem>` property on the type which is ignored by the `XmlSerializer`.

```
public class TypeToSerialize
{
    [XmlArray("myThings")]
    [XmlArrayItem("This")]
    public List<string> myThingsToSerialize { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> MyThings
    {
        get { return this.myThingsToSerialize.Select(x => new SelectListItem {Text = x, Value = x}).ToList(); }
    }
}
```

You do not mention anything about how this list is maintained so you would have to make sure that mutations happen through the string list OR add some additional methods to help with that like `void Add(SelectListItem item)` which would add to the `List<string>` (same with remove etc.);